# Horizontal Scroll on IE8 + half black section

Tags: internet-explorer

Below website is showing horizontal scroll bar with black-half portion. On chrome and FF its ok, but on IE8 it have design issue.

www.aftermoonsolar.com is the website.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the row width to 100% makes the black section go away. You end up with some unused space along the right side, but you might be able to fix that.

```
.row {
    width: 100%
}
```

If it's only a problem in IE 8, you'll probably want to put that in an IE8-specific stylesheet (or in conditional comments.)